# mkdir problem PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in
```

I keep getting this annoying message when trying to create new directories. my function is

```
mkdir("../".$a."/".$b);

$a = an existing filepath
$b = new folder i wish to create
```

function is executed from another directory: my structure looks like this:

```
/htroot/site/c/ <- where im executing the function
/htroot/site/a/b <- where i wish to create the directories.
```

if i execute the following, it creates the desired effect but in the same directory as the function.

```
mkdir($a."/".$b);
```

HI ALL THANKS FOR THE HOT RESPONSES

```
C:\wamp\www\book\admin\import //is my __DIR__ for that script
C:\wamp\www\book\admin\property // already exists

C:\wamp\www\book\admin\property\name // want i want end result
```

Comment: Is this a plain PHP script run from the command prompt?  Is it included by some other script?

Comment: You can check what the script thinks the current directory is with `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: trying...now. its part of a script in a file /htroot/site/c checking what dirname has to say

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.3, `__DIR__` is quicker

Comment: I've added an example to my answer that includes an important point raised in @hobbs' answer (re symlinks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how your function is included, the PWD could be anywhere. You're best to use an absolute path.

You can also grab the current script's directory using `__DIR__` (v5.3+) or `dirname(__FILE__)`

For example

```
// use realpath to resolve any symbolic links
$newDir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../' . $a) . '/' . $b;
mkdir($newDir);
```

See [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Comment: Oops, changed it again. Remembered seeing something about realpath failing on non-existant paths in some environments so removed `$b` from the function call

Comment: @Phil awesome answer man. I'm currently trying to implement your answer. However, i echoed $newDir to check its value and it is showing c:\wamp\book\admin\property/name

Comment: @claw That's fine. PHP can use forward or backslash interchangeably in Windows. If you want to be *really* thorough, use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` in place of any slashes. Or are you referring to the missing "www" mentioned in your question?

Comment: @Phil sweet. using the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. still receiving Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory. Pardon my ignorance, why doesnt PHP just create the DIR if it doesnt exist?

Comment: @claw Does the `c:\wamp\book\admin\property` directory exist? You can recursively create directories by passing `true` as the third argument to `mkdir` however use with caution.

Comment: You can force `mkdir` to create any missing directories by passing a `true` to the 3rd parameter:  `mkdir('/dir/that/might/be/missing', 0777, true)` -- but you might not get the path you expected.

Comment: @claw Yeah, could you clarify what the correct path should be? `C:\wamp\book\...` or should it be `C:\wamp\www\book\...`

Answer (score 2):

Whatever `"../$a"` is, there's no such directory, however much you want there to be. Maybe there's a symlink, and `..` isn't the directory you think it is.

Comment: ok cool. is ../ correct for the path of the parent folder? so b = ../